# I want to know what condition to write in while loop

Tags: javascript, while-loop

```
var understand = true;  
while(/* ... */) {  
    console.log("I'm learning while loops!");  
    understand = false;  
    }
```

I want to print "I'm learning while loops!" so what condition need to write in loop?

Comment: How many time you want to print 'I'm learning while loops'?

Comment: need to print only once

Comment: `while(understand)` should do for printing once.

Comment: More importantly, reading this will help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while

Comment: wht if i wnt to repeat it fr couple of times ??

Comment: @SankalpDeshpande please see `Edit1` in my answer. And have a look at link posted by @techfoobar or go through any good tutorial on the internet about `javascript loops`.

Comment: var loop = function(){
 while(loop<3){
  //Your code goes here!
   console.log("I'm looping!");  
 }
};

loop();

i tried bt nt succeeded :(

Comment: @SankalpDeshpande please see `Edit2` in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
while(understand){
    console.log("I'm learning while loops!");  
    understand = false;  
}
```

**Edit1:**

If you want your loop to run for number of times:

```
var i=0;
while(i<10){    //suppose you want to run your loop for 10 times.
    console.log("I'm learning while loops!");  
    i++;
}
```

**Edit2:** (Reply to code in comments)

You are using `loop` as a function name and checking same in the while loop which is wrong.
Try this:

```
var myFunctionName = function()
{
    var myVariableName = 0;
    while(myVariableName<3)
    { 
        console.log("In loop" + myVariableName);
        myVariableName++;
    }
};
myFunctionName();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to execute your while loop once.

```
var understand = false; // not yet

while(understand !== true){  
    console.log("I'm learning while loops!");  
    understand = true; // I do now!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The while loop will continue to execute while the condition evaluates to true. So it really depends on the condition you want. If you just want a single loop, and judging by your code, you probably want the following:

```
var understand = true;  
while(understand) {  
    console.log("I'm learning while loops!");  
    understand = false;  
}
```

This is like saying: "while understand equals true, then execute the loop"

---

It is worth mentioning that the variable name `understand` doesn't make much sense starting as `true` and being set to `false` when you want to break the loop (assuming that you want to break the loop when you **do** understand). So the following would be more logical:

```
var understand = false;//don't yet understand, so enter loop
while(!understand) {  
    console.log("I'm learning while loops!");  
    understand = true;//now I understand, so break loop
}
```

This is like saying: "while understand equals false, then execute the loop"

Answer (score 0):

```
var understand = true;  

while( understand == true){  
    console.log("I'm learning while loops!");  
    understand = false;  
}
```